# Long polling новые сообщения

Tags: mysqli, ajax, php, long-poll

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно сделать уведомление о новых сообщения для пользователей. Используя `Long polling`. Что есть на данный момент.

Клиент:

```
function getmess() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "notif.php",
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#count").html(result);
            setTimeout('getmess', 10000);
        }
    });
}
```

Обработчик notif.php:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }

    session_start();

    $MY_ID = $_SESSION['id'];

    while (true) {
        $result = $mysqli - > query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE user_get='$MY_ID' AND status='1' ");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row[0].
                "";
            }
            flush();
            exit;
        }
        sleep(5);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что когда приходит новое сообщение блок count не обновляется. Если повесить событие `onclick="getmess();"` на кнопку, то при нажатии на нее счетчик обновляется, но мне нужно чтобы он обновлялся сразу как приходит новое сообщение.

Comment: @RageXL, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Есть мнение, что в том виде, как у вас реализовано - "сразу" не получится. 
Простое решение - оберните функцию getmess() в конструкцию setInterval, с интервалом 5-10 секунд.
Это способ тупой, но действенный, однако сразу готовьтесь к скачкообразному росту запросов на сервер.

Надежное решение - использование веб-сокетов.

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "notif.php",
    data: {
        "id": id
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#count").html(result);
    }
});
},10000);
```

Comment: Теперь другая проблема. Сделал так

(function getmess(){
    $.ajax({
 url:"get_mess.php", 
 data:{"id":id},
 type:"POST",
 timeout: 10000,
 complete:getmess,
 success:function(result){
 $("#count").html(result);
 }
 });
})();

Функция вызывается сама, но запрос отсылается каждую секунду, хотя в timeout указанно 10 секунд. На изменения значения timeout вообще не реагирует, какое значение не впиши,- все равно запрос идет каждую секунду. Подскажите в чем проблема ?

Comment: так неправильно. я добавил пример в свой ответ.

Comment: Суть в чем - мне надо отсылать запрос на сервер и ждать ответ 10 секунд, если ответа нет, то отсылать опять запрос и ждать 10 секунд ответа.